# NSFileManager removeItemAtPath clears the contents of the directory, but not the actual directory itself

Tags: iphone, directory, nsfilemanager

I have some code that copies all the directories from "/Documents" to "Library/Caches/". The code is as follows:

```
NSString *oldPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/", NSHomeDirectory()];
NSString *newPath = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Caches/", NSHomeDirectory()];
NSError *error = nil;

// get the list of all files and directories

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileList = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:oldPath error:&error];

if(error != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"\n\n\n1. There was an error in the file operation: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return;
}

for(NSString *file in fileList) 
{
    NSString *path = [oldPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];

    NSLog(@"The path for the file is: %@", path);

    BOOL isDir = NO;

    BOOL dirExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:(&isDir)];

    if(isDir && dirExists) 
    {
        //Move to the new location
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path toPath:[newPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:&error];
        if(error != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"\n\n\n2. There was an error in the file operation: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else
        {
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];

            if(error != nil)
                NSLog(@"\n\n\n3. There was an error in the file operation: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}
```

The copy works fine. I can see all the directories copied to the new location.

The problem is that the empty directories still remain in the Documents folder. I read up on `removeItemAtPath` in the docs and it says there that the contents of the directory are deleted. Whether the actual directory itself is deleted or not has no mention.

Could someone tell me what could be going wrong in the code? Why do the empty directories still remain?

EDIT:

On the first pass, when the directories exist in Documents, but not in Library/Caches, `removeItemAtPath` does not throw an error. The empty directories still remain in Documents, though. On the second pass of the above code, it attempts to remove the empty directories and `removeItemAtPath` throws a cocoa error 516 which is basically file not found - this is weird, because I can still see those empty directories.

Also, I'm running this code on iPhone Simulator 4.3.2 and iPhone Simulator 5.0, and monitoring the directory structure on my Mac in /Users/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be happening because of the trailing "/" in "/Documents/".  Try removing the trailing "/" from the first 2 lines, or use this:

```
NSString *oldPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *newPath = [NSString pathWithComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSHomeDirectory() , @"Library", @"Caches", nil]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileList = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:oldPath error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"\n\n\n1. There was an error in the file operation: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return;
}

for (NSString *file in fileList)  {
    NSString *path = [oldPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    NSLog(@"The path for the file is: %@", path);

    BOOL isDir = NO;

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) {
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path toPath:[newPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:&error];
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"\n\n\n2. There was an error in the file operation: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];

            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"\n\n\n3. There was an error in the file operation: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi chown, thank you for the response. Sadly, I tried the code you posted but it doesn't solve it. I'm wondering if it's just a simulator issue?

Comment: @Sid That is very possible because the code looks pretty good.  If it works on a device, then theres gotta be a permissions issue (or something similar) preventing the sim from removing that directory.

Comment: So testing on device does not show any of those logs for file operation errors; I think that means it works on the device, though I still can't be a 100% sure because I don't know any way to see the file system for myself.... Thanks for all your help!

Comment: To see the file system for yourself, connect your device to Xcode, select the organiser, select Applications under your device on the left, select the application you are developing, at this point go and make a cup of coffee if there are a lot of files, the file system appears as if by magic (although the app bundle is hidden). You can download the visible files and folders to read by clicking on the download button below. It will be stored on you Mac as a package so to see the files there you have to right click and select Show Package Contents

Comment: @Martin I especially like the coffee part ;)